# Pointer assignment to variable where only dummy is target

Tags: pointers, fortran, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, fortran95

To avoid an XY-problem I will first summarize my overall goal.

We have a large legacy codebase of fortran77 code, that implemented their own memory allocation.
It consists of a 1D `Work` Array that is equivalenced to be used with different types.
It looks roughly like this:

```
      Real*8       Work(1:IWORKLEN)
      Real*4       sWork(1:IWORKLEN)
      Integer      iWork(1:IWORKLEN)
      Character*1  cWork(1:2*ICWORKLEN)

      Equivalence (Work,sWork)
      Equivalence (Work,iWork)
      Equivalence (Work,cWork)
```

The custom allocator will then return indices in this work array.
We have nicer allocations for new code, but a large part still uses this legacy code.

One of the obvious drawbacks is that everything is a 1D array and the programmer has to do the manual pointer arithmetic to index multidimensional arrays.
For this reason it would be great to reinterpret parts of this array as n-dimensional arrays using pointers.
Unfortunately one cannot add the `target` attribute to equivalenced variables.

While playing around I created this minimal example, which solves our problems without the need for `target`:

```
program test_dummy_target
    implicit none(type, external)
    integer, allocatable :: work(:)
    integer, pointer :: M(:, :) => null()

    work = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    M => recast(work, 2, 2)

    write(*, *) M(1, :)
    write(*, *) M(2, :)

contains

    function recast(vec, n, m) result(mat)
        integer, target, intent(in) :: vec(:)
        integer, intent(in) :: n, m
        integer, pointer :: mat(:, :)
        mat(1 : n, 1 : m) => vec(:)
    end function
end program
```

On the other hand

```
program test_dummy_target
    implicit none
    integer, allocatable :: vec(:)
    integer, pointer :: M(:, :) => null()

    vec = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    M(1 : 2, 1 : 2) => vec

    write(*, *) M(1, :)
    write(*, *) M(2, :)
end program
```

does not compile, because `target` is required for `vec`.

So now my question:

1. Is there undefined behaviour lurking in my minimal example? I don't get why the first example should work properly, if the second one does not.
2. How do I properly recast the 1D `Work` array without a copy?

Comment: I cannot make an equivalenced variable a target, so I cannot use this way of pointer bounds remapping. Otherwise it would be basically my second example.

Comment: If an object doesn't have the target attribute then it can't be a target of a pointer; if not using pointer manipulation then 'recasting' can be of the other forms in answers to the linked question. If none applies, then you're looking at copies.